# Android print stack trace

Tags: android

How can I get the equivalent of a printStackTrace in android? I know I can log an error, by passing in a tag name and a String to the logging method, but that just gives me a nullpointerexception. If I call e.printStackTrace(), where is this data printed to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using eclipse make sure you have `LogCat` window opended. You can find it under

**Window-> Show View-> Other -> Under Android -> LogCat**

*updated:2014 July*

OR if you are using Android Studio you can find it under

**Window menu -> Show view -> Logcat**

`LogCat` is like a console in normal JAVA. Your `e.printstacktrace()` would appear in LogCat as well.

Answer (score 17):

```
Log.e("mytag", "mymessage",ex);
```

Answer (score 2):

The data is still printed to the DDMS logs with 
    e.printStackTrace();
You can also use 
    Log.e("Tag", "Description", e); 
which will print the logs as well.  DDMS is located under android-sdk/tools/ddms and logs will be shown in the bottom pane on launch.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in case you already haven't, you should be wrapping your code in a `try-catch` structure, like this, for example:

```
private String TAG = "MyMethodName";  // change this to anything that makes sense to you       
try {
    ...
    Log.d(TAG, "processed OK");
} catch (Exception except) {
    Log.e(TAG,"CRASH StackTrace: "+ Arrays.toString(except.getStackTrace()));
}
```

This pseudocode will show a complete stack trace.

NEWBIE ALERT:
Before publishing app, don't forget to "comment out" (using `//`) this and all debugging features that may be used to expose the internals of your code.  Anyone who plugs a device running your code with ADB enabled will be able to access LogCat (where `Log` publishes).